# Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference [5.6]

Tags: php

I've got error from PHP Script for streaming.

> Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
>   /home/x/public_html/xstream/episodestream.php on line 114

```
<?php 
$url = $cap['seo'];
$numero    = end(explode('-', $url));
$palabra1  = str_replace($numero, '', $url);
$final     = $palabra1;
?> // line 114
<?php if ($numero <= 1) {} else {?> // line 115
```

Comment: its working for me:-https://eval.in/851243  . so can you provide more detail like what is there in `$url`?

Comment: try storing the `explode('-', $url)` to a variable before using `end()`.  `$x=explode('-',$url); $numero = end($x)`;

Comment: Seems like end() is the problem, try assigning explode('-', $url) to a variable.

Comment: @AlivetoDie, you need to up the error reporting to include E_STRICT. E.g.:https://eval.in/851249

Comment: @AlivetoDie, It's //Friendly URL - function setSeo($url)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read the [PHP doc of end](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php):

> The array. This array is passed by reference because it is modified by the function. This means **you must pass it a real variable and not a function returning an array** because only actual variables may be passed by reference.

Which means you cannot pass `explode` function directly to `end`. Instead you need to do in two steps:

```
$var = explode('-', $url);
$numero = end($var);
```

Comment: I've got error.

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' on line 327

Please look this screenshot: http://prntscr.com/ge4wap

Comment: You are using `$numero` before initializing. Which is 327 line?

Comment: I removed <?php } ?>, It's working now. Thank you for help! I will donate your PayPal $5. If you want. I would like to give you staff developer to help anime streaming. Can we contact on skype or discord?

Comment: @SamettoChan Oh donation! That's great. Please donate it to StackOverflow. They do great job here for free. They deserve it.

Comment: Thank you! Can you give me a link for StackOverflow donation?

Comment: @SamettoChan What is the problem?

Comment: You gave details PHP to fixed. It is working. But the episode hasn't real-time by anime for episode system 1,2,3,4,5,6.